# How to optimize malloc() or dynamically fill memory of an unknown size?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, dynamic, malloc

I'm just playing around in C, and I wanted a function that would generate the Fibonacci Sequence up to a variable maximum term and be returned as a pointer to an array.  The code below works just fine.

But my question is actually whether it can be optimized at all?  I'm generating the same fibonacci sequence **twice**; first to find how many *fibterms* there are up to the *maxterm* and allocate enough memory to fit all the terms, and a second time to fill that memory with the terms I've now found twice.

Am I overlooking something more key to malloc() or is there a way to combine these two loops?  Can I continually be calling malloc and copying the old fib into a new one?  Is that bad to be repeatedly calling for new memory?

```
int* genFib(int maxterm) 
{   
    // generate a way for x to be the fibonacci term
    // with y being the previous term
    int x = 1, y = 1;

    // fibterms is a global variable that counts the
    // number of terms, to create the right size array.
    // it needed to be global to find the size elsewhere
    do
    {
        int temp = x;
        x += y;
        y = temp;
        fibterms++;
    }
    while (x < maxterm);

    // the array has enough space allocated now, but
    // is empty for the moment.
    int* fib = malloc(sizeof(int) * fibterms);   

    // i need to now redo my previous loop just to
    // fill the array with the correct terms, so all
    // counters and terms are reset.
    x = 1, y = 1;
    fibterms = 0;

    // same loop as above, but 
    // filling the array this time
    do
    {
        fib[fibterms] = x;
        int temp = x;
        x += y;
        y = temp;
        fibterms++;
    }
    while (x < maxterm);
    return fib;
}
```

Comment: Try `malloc()`-ing for the array **element** individually inside the first loop itself.

Comment: You might like to have a look at the `realloc()` system call: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html

Comment: You can use realloc to extend the size of an existing array, but most of the time this implies copying the old array into the new one (realloc will do this for you) and this takes time. So your solution is probably not so bad.

Comment: OT: I'd use `unsigned` but `int`, as no negative values are needed her.

Comment: BTW: there is not readon for fibterm being global. I'd make it local to the genFib function.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I'm glad to hear my solution isn't as bad as I thought.  The reason fibterm is global is when I try to access the terms from other functions, sizeof(fib) when fib = fibGen(40) wasn't giving the correct length, so I just replaced it with fibterms.  Unless I'm supposed to use sizeof(*fib), which seems reasonable but isn't what I read.

Comment: @BUSY: sizeof gives the amount of storage, in bytes, associated with a variable. In your case sizeof(fib) is always 4 (or 8 on a 64 bits system), that is the number of bytes a pointer uses. sizeof(*fib) is the same as sizeof(int) (normally 4) becase fib is a pointer to int.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: So how can I find the number of terms from a different function?  I've only returned a pointer to the first term, does the new function have any way to find when the *i*th term changes from an int to garbage?

Comment: @BUSY: you can't. You must keep track of the size of your array. The global variable method you use is one possibility. Another possibility is to add a second parameter like this `int* genFib(int maxterm, int *fibterms)` and use `*fibterms` instead of `fibterms` inside the `genFib`.

Comment: One approach could be to find an approximation for fibterms: Wikipedia has a formula to find an index from a Fibonacci number at the end of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding: `n(F)=⌊log (F * √5 * ½) ⌋

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int* fib = malloc(sizeof(int));   
    x = 1, y = 1;
    fibterms = 0;

    // same loop as above, but 
    // filling the array this time
    do
    {
        fib[fibterms] = x;
        int temp = x;
        x += y;
        y = temp;
        fibterms++;
        fib = (int *)realloc(fib , sizeof(int)*(fibterms+1));//fibterms is a int from 0
    }
```

Comment: When extending a dynamic memory area like this doubling it in size each time it is full has a better complexity. It means that you call 'malloc' fewer times as the size of the area grows.

Comment: @Will Is that done through realloc(fib, sizeof(fib) * 2)?  Or do I need to store a new variable to remember the size of my array?

Comment: you will probably want to store both the size of your array, and the size of the block you currently have allocated. If there are too many elements to fit in the block, double the size of the block.